# PHP change font with @font-face

Tags: php, fonts

I have a code in my cpanel like this, the font file is in my cpanel folder

its my css code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AA';
    src:url('link.tff');
}
```

I try to open my browser and type "link.tff", the font pop up as download.. but I try to use this font, the font not change

its my php code

```
.nav a {
    height: 3em;
    font-family: 'AA';
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

how to make it right?

Comment: did you put link.ttf font file and your css in same directory in `public_html`?

Comment: Everything is there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: link.tff is a link to the font, i try type it on url browser box and it can download the font